# OpenGL 4.1 SDL2 Mac OS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, sdl

I'm trying to create OpenGL 4.1 core context on Mac OS Yosimite (10.10.2) with SDL2.
But all I managed to get is 3.2 context with GLSL 150 (!). My GL initialization code looks like this:

```
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);


    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

Videocard: AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

Comment: If your notebook has an additional integrated graphic chip (present on a lot of Intel i processors), make sure you're using the AMD card for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to add a comment but don't have enough reputation yet. I think you have likely not added the OpenGL framework to your project, or you could be including the wrong OpenGL .h file.

To add the framework: Go to your project settings, then Build Phases, then Link Binary with Libraries and then add the OpenGL framework.

What .h file are you using? I had problems creating a context with OpenGL.h but no problems with gl3.h